# How can I preserve execute bits for files during 'cf push' for Node apps?

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I need to push a node application that will be executing a bash script and the script file needs to have the execute bit set. Can the cf command line utility allow me to set execute permission?

If it doesn't, can I do something during the staging cycle of my app to set execute permission bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script that has the execute bit set will also have it set when being pushed.

If you need to have a script invoked as part of staging or pushing the app, there are two options:

**Invoke script during staging**

Use `scripts.preinstall` stanza in `package.json` to run scripts during **staging** (during `npm install`, see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) for more options), and include that script with your application:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "preinstall": "./configure"
},
```

**Invoke script after staging**

If the script can be run before app is started, but **after staging**, use `.profile.d`.  Before your app is started in the container (after staging), a bash shell will run all scripts in your `.profile.d` folder.

For example, I could have a `my_app/.profile.d/aScript.sh` file with:

`export key=value` or `chmod +x some_file`